# Add additional information to auto-enrolled certificates (Windows Active Directory CA)

Tags: active-directory, certificate, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services

I successfully enabled auto-enrollment for client computer certificates within our Active Directory domain.

However, I want to include additional details in the auto-enrolled certificate such as the organizational unit (OU) the client computer is located in. I can do this just fine by manually creating an CSR and submitting it to our CA, however, I wan't to use auto-enrollment.

I can't, for the heck of it, find a way on how to include additional information in auto-enrolled certificates. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the certificate template editor (certtmpl.msc), switch to Subject tab and select **Full distinguished name** in the Subject Name Format dropdown list:

[image]

this will include full Active Directory DN for the specified client account.